# How to install r8168 driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

[I used this link to solve my problem with r8169](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134878/make-linux-load-specific-driver-for-given-device-realtek-nic)

But when I've made

`modprobe r8168
echo 1168 8169 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8168/new_id`

I didn't get 0000:05:01.0 in r8168 folder and I can't perform

```
# echo 0000:05:01.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8168/bind
```

How can I set up r8168?

Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo lspci -v | egrep "Ethernet|Network|Gigabit" -A15

05:01.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
Subsystem: D-Link System Inc DGE-528T PCI Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 31
I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
Memory at f7520000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
Expansion ROM at f7500000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

What problem I have with internet. 
Internet turn off sometimes and I can't do anything except reboot

Comment: At first please specify you Ubuntu version, then show us your network hardware. Please add output of `sudo lspci -v | egrep "Ethernet|Network|Gigabit" -A15` to the question. What problems do you have with Ethernet?

Comment: Hello as far as I see your answer to this new problem is dated on 2014. It has to do something with new kernel and even newest package of driver with uninstalling and blacklisting the r8169 doesn't help. There is also bug report. So on my opinion we have to wait the solution. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1752772